# Why is an extra blank figure being plotted when returning matplotlib figure object in recursive function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

Say I have the following simple function to return a matplotlib figure object:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def return_mpl_fig(x,y):
    mpl_fig = plt.figure()
    ax = mpl_fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    return mpl_fig
```

I can convert the matplotlib figure object into a plotly figure object and plot it:

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.tools as tls

x=[i for i in range(1,11)]
y=[i for i in range(1,11)]

mpl_fig = return_mpl_fig(x,y)
plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig)

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
iplot(plotly_fig)
```

[image]

But if instead of the simple function I make it a recursive function, it plots a blank figure in addition:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def return_mpl_fig(x,y):
    mpl_fig = plt.figure()
    ax = mpl_fig.add_subplot(111)
    if len(x)>5:
        return return_mpl_fig(x[:5],y[:5])
    ax.plot(x,y)
    return mpl_fig

from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.tools as tls

x=[i for i in range(1,11)]
y=[i for i in range(1,11)]

mpl_fig = return_mpl_fig(x,y)
plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig)

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
iplot(plotly_fig)
```

[image]

Why is that? And how do I prevent it?

Comment: Not directly your issue, but `x=[i for i in range(1,11)]` can be either `x = list(range (1, 11))` or even just `x = range(1, 11)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have modified the library that you are using to create a reference to your figure, you need to be mindful of **how** you are creating that reference so you don't create unnecessary figures in your function. I believe a fairly simple change would be to write your function using `gcf()` and `gca()` which return instances of the current figure or axes if they exist, otherwise create new ones:

```
def return_mpl_fig(x,y):
    mpl_fig = plt.gcf()
    ax = mpl_fig.gca()
    if len(x)>5:
        return return_mpl_fig(x[:5],y[:5])
    ax.plot(x,y)
    return mpl_fig
```

Comment: This was just an example code to demonstrate the issue. In my actual code, I use a complicated library (written by someone else) that produces a plot, which upon digging into the issue I found has recursion in it upon triggering an if condition. So, if that condition is not triggered, it plots correctly; otherwise, it give an error actually, not just an extra plot like in this demo example. Here's the recursion bit in the actual function which I modified to return the figure object: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/1330bd979e0fb2e943c44e99231e579c9b4f0999/shap/plots/dependence.py#L82-L85

Comment: If you've modified the library code, I've amended my answer to propose a solution that should avoid creating unnecessary figures

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't make any difference - it still gives the same errors.